# how to filter the data from the database. i am using bootstrap blazor

Tags: blazor-bootstrap

I can only filter the id, firstname and lastname. The department, division and status I cannot filter it because they are foreign keys.

```
<Grid @ref="grid" TItem="Employee" class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped"       DataProvider="EmployeesDataProvider" AllowFiltering="true" Responsive="true">
    <GridToolbar>
        <InputText @bind-Value="@filterValue" Placeholder="Filter by First Name" />
    </GridToolbar>
    <GridColumn TItem="Employee" HeaderText="Id" PropertyName="Id">
        @context.Id
    </GridColumn>
    <GridColumn TItem="Employee" HeaderText="First Name" PropertyName="FirstName">
        @context.FirstName
    </GridColumn>
    <GridColumn TItem="Employee" HeaderText="Last Name" PropertyName="LastName">
        @context.LastName
    </GridColumn>
    <GridColumn TItem="Employee" HeaderText="Gender" PropertyName="Genders" >
        @context.Genders.Name
    </GridColumn>
    <GridColumn TItem="Employee" HeaderText="Division" PropertyName="Division">
        @context.Division.Name
    </GridColumn>
    <GridColumn TItem="Employee" HeaderText="Status" PropertyName="Status">
        @context.Status.Name
    </GridColumn>
    </Grid>

@code {
    BlazorBootstrap.Grid<Employee> grid;
    private IEnumerable<Employee> employees;
    private string filterValue;
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    }

           private async Task<GridDataProviderResult<Employee>>     EmployeesDataProvider(GridDataProviderRequest<Employee> request)
    {
        if (employees is null)
            employees = await EmployeeModelService.GetEmployees();

        var filteredEmployees = employees;
      
        return await Task.FromResult(request.ApplyTo(filteredEmployees));
    }

    private async Task<IEnumerable<Employee>> GetEmployees()
    {
        return await EmployeeModelService.GetEmployees();
    }
}
```

I want to filter all the data from the table.

Comment: any luck in finding a response for this?